# How to reuse an Xcode project into a new project? Static library, Framework, Targets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, code-reuse

I built an iOS project (actually workspace because of Pods) that is 100% functional, with its logic and UI (Storyboard and xibs). Now I would like to reuse this app/project as a "core" for future apps.

I've been searching about it and there are several solutions like Static libraries, Frameworks and Targets. But I am not sure which one would be the best in my case. I would like to reuse all the UI part as well.

I saw that most of the people agree that the best approach for reusing code is static libraries, even thought it looks not so straight forward. But I think for reusing UI probably Targets is the best solution. The problem I see is that if a build 10 apps based on my core project, the new project will be huge, so probably it is not the best option.

I don't know if you guys have any better idea or opinion.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you can do, and I will try to go through them.

If you have minor changes on your "base" app, then the best thing would be using targets(build schemes). This way you can add things to build phases and therefore, add files that you need. This might be the quickest possible way to do what you want but here are some drawbacks: What if you have 5 apps, and for each one you have QA and prod. That 10 build phases. If you keep using your app in no time you will find hard to manage it.

Another thing could be to create different project, and include all the files you have (and you need), inherit from there and have extended functionality/UI/UX. This is slower approach then number 1, but you will have dependency on the files that you might change in one app and don't want to propagate that change in other apps. So the drawback would be that you have to be extra careful, and plan a lot of things in advance.

Third thing could be to create base app group(or project) and then you are certain what to do, where and what that change could do to other apps(since you know that this file is actually being reused).

And finally, there is a framework, which is my favorite. I am working on one project that inherits base app and we found that is a huge problem. You start separated and then, one thing by one, you have entangled code for specific app and base app like headphones in pocket. And if you don't refactor it ASAP, it will became really hard to resolve these kind of issue. Not to mention merging and other stuff. Here is an excellent article about creating framework http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios . Off course, there is a price to pay and that's every change that you create you must update library and add it again to project. This thing can be easily forgotten and if you are working in team could produce build crash.

All after all, you predicate that you will have more then 5 apps, so I would say go with the framework. This way you will have much cleaner and separated app, and won't have to think about changing things and how these changes would affect your other apps.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Since you are already working with it and you recommend it I will go with the Framework.

Comment: @RubenX Did you go with Framework eventually? I'm going thru the same process as you are. Would love to hear your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a custom project template. I did it perfectly today. I had the same needs as your. Follow this link: https://github.com/reidmain/Xcode-6-Project-Templates/tree/master/iOS%20Application.xctemplate
Download it. You can add all the files from existing project into this template, storyboards too. If you have any doubts I will help you.